# Outputing value of TrueClass / FalseClass to integer or string/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to figure out if there is an easy way to do the following short of adding to_i method to TrueClass/FalseClass.

Here is a dilemma:
I have a boolean field in my rails app - that is obviously stored as Tinyint in mysql. However - I need to generate xml based of the data in mysql and send it to  customer - there SOAP service requires the field in question to have 0 or 1 as the value of this field. So at the time of the xml generation I need to convert my False to 0 and my True to 1 ( which is how they are stored in the DB). Since True & False lack to_i method I could write some if statement that generate either 1 or 0 depending on true/false state. However I have about 10 of these indicators and creating and if/else for each is not very DRY. So what you recommend I do?

Or I could add a to_i method to the True / False class.  But I'm not sure where should I scope it in my rails app? Just inside this particular model or somewhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a file such as `lib/boolean_ints.rb` and monkey-patch a `to_i` method to `TrueClass` and `FalseClass`, as you suggested. Then, in the models or controllers in which you need to use the `to_i` method, you could just put

```
require 'boolean_ints'
```

at the top, and they'd be available for use.

Comment: @mipadi - related to this, is there a specific convention on how things should be structured/named/layed out in lib?

Comment: I don't know of a convention for `lib` per se. I usually just try to name things as clearly and succinctly as possible.

Answer (score 5):

### Extend TrueClass and FalseClass with `humanize` and `to_i`.

This comes up in most of my projects so I use an initializer *(if you're using Rails)* that adds these two helpful methods to each class, like so:

**config/initializers/true_and_false.rb**

```
class TrueClass
  def humanize
    'Yes'
  end

  def to_i
    1
  end
end

class FalseClass
  def humanize
    'No'
  end

  def to_i
    0
  end
end
```

Then it makes rendering `true` very easy for both **"human consumption"** and **"machine consumption"**:

```
> true.humanize     #=> Yes
> true.to_i         #=> 1

> false.humanize    #=> No
> false.to_i        #=> 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just monkeypatch the `TrueClass` and `FalseClass` in your app, near that particular model: any implementation of `to_i` on true and false are likely to be the same.

```
irb(main):004:0> true.to_i
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_i' for true:TrueClass
        from (irb):4
irb(main):005:0> class TrueClass
irb(main):006:1>  def to_i
irb(main):007:2>   1
irb(main):008:2>  end
irb(main):009:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):010:0>
irb(main):011:0* true.to_i
=> 1
```

But to avoid monkeypatching, is there any reason you couldn't just use the ternary operator?  If that's still not DRY enough for you, wrap it up in a method.

```
irb(main):012:0> true ? 1 : 0
=> 1
irb(main):013:0> false ? 1 : 0
=> 0
```

Of course, that works with non-boolean variables as well:

```
irb(main):019:0* 1234 ? 1 : 0
=> 1
irb(main):020:0> nil ? 1 : 0
=> 0
```

Comment: @Mark - I already did this - but I asked if there is a way to do this  "short of adding to_i method to TrueClass/FalseClass." or using if else statements - which is what ternary operator really is, I was trying to see if there is another way to do this that I don't know off.  However it doesn't make sense to me thou - that False.to_s works and produces "false" string, but to_i is not implemented in the core class.  Thank you thou for your response.

Answer (score 2):

**Update: This 'solution' is dangerous and should not be used!**

You can also try:

```
value.object_id / 2
```

I'm not sure how well this works across implementations.

To get rid of the duplication of having to repeat this 10 times, I would still recommend creating a method:

```
def boolean_to_i value
  value.object_id / 2
end
```

No real need to monkey-patch, though.

Comment: Just tested this, and it works on MRI 1.8 and 1.9, and on JRuby, but not on Rubinius (where the object id's for true and false are 19 and 10, respectively).

Comment: This is definitely wrong and even dangerous. In Ruby 2.0 TrueClass.object_id is defined as 20.

Comment: I agree. It depends too much on an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
5 - bool.to_s.length
```

This will always work because `true.to_s` is `"true"` and `false.to_s` is `"false"`, and `"true".length` is 4, while `"false".length` is 5.